# is SwingWorker.done() guaranteed to execute after the worker's last invocation of SwingWorker.process()?

Tags: swingworker

Here's what the documentation for SwingWorker says:
- `doInBackground()` executes in a worker thread
- `process()` executes asynchronously on the Event Dispatch thread (AWT EDT). It's execution is unpredictable with respect to calls to `publish()` in the worker thread
- `done()` executes in the AWT EDT after `doInBackground()` has completed

I cannot see anything that says the last invocation of `process()` is **always** executed before `done()` (they both run on the same thread).

I have multiple calls to `publish()` from `doInBackground()`; the published objects are picked up in `process()` and used to update a GUI with progress reports. A literal interpretation of the documentation could imply that it's *possible* for `done()` to be scheduled on the EDT before the very last execution of `process()`, because `done()` is guaranteed to execute after the worker thread but `process()` is documented as being unpredictable.

All my tests show that `done()` runs after the last `publish()` (which makes sense, and it's what I want), but has anyone seen documentation or dug into the code to verify if SwingWorker is designed to guarantee that behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is no. See DSquare's answer linked to below.

> `publish()` doesn't directly schedule `process`, it sets a timer which
>   will fire the scheduling of a `process()` block in the `EDT` after `DELAY`.

Comment: For the record, this answer is wrong. You can find an example code of a done() executed before process() and the explanation of why that happens [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958793/swingworker-done-is-executed-before-process-calls-are-finished)