# SwingWorker, done() is executed before process() calls are finished

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have been working with [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)s for a while and have ended up with a strange behavior, at least for me. I clearly understand that due to performance reasons several invocations to [publish()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish-V...-) method are coallesced in one invocation. It makes perfectly sense to me and I suspect SwingWorker keeps some kind of queue to process all that calls.

According to [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and API, when SwingWorker ends its execution, either [doInBackground()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#doInBackground--) finishes normally or worker thread is cancelled from the outside, then [done()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done--) method is invoked. So far so good.

But I have an example (similar to shown in tutorials) where there are `process()` method  calls done ***after*** `done()` method is executed. Since both methods execute in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) I would expect `done()` be executed after all `process()` invocations are finished. In other words:

#### Expected:

```
Writing...
Writing...
Stopped!
```

#### Result:

```
Writing...
Stopped!
Writing...
```

#### Sample code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Demo {

    private SwingWorker<Void, String> worker;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private Action startAction, stopAction;

    private void createAndShowGui() {

        startAction = new AbstractAction("Start writing") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Demo.this.startWriting();
                this.setEnabled(false);
                stopAction.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };

        stopAction = new AbstractAction("Stop writing") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Demo.this.stopWriting();
                this.setEnabled(false);
                startAction.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(new JButton(startAction));
        buttonsPanel.add(new JButton(stopAction));

        textArea = new JTextArea(30, 50);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void startWriting() {
        stopWriting();
        worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                while(!isCancelled()) {
                    publish("Writing...\n");
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                String string = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
                textArea.append(string);
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                textArea.append("Stopped!\n");
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }

    private void stopWriting() {
        if(worker != null && !worker.isCancelled()) {
            worker.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo().createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a known bug http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6826514

Comment: But also see [JDK-6826514 - SwingWorker: done() called before doInBackground() returns, when cancelled](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6826514) closed as "not an issue"

Comment: Empirically, the effect is not seen when the worker's background latency exceeds [`DELAY`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11838349/230513).

Comment: Finally, a **good** question on my front page.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204141/swingworker-when-exactly-is-called-done-method

Comment: Thanks @kmort I didn't see that topic when I asked my question. Interesting :-)

Comment: No problem. I wanted to get the cross-post up there because I spent half a day thinking I was crazy until I found the one I linked to. :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

This happens because publish() doesn't directly schedule `process`, it sets a timer which will fire the scheduling of a process() block in the EDT after `DELAY`. So when the worker is cancelled there is still a timer waiting to schedule a process() with the data of the last publish. The reason for using a timer is to implement the optimization where a single process may be executed with the combined data of several publishes.

**LONG ANSWER:**

Let's see how publish() and cancel interact with each other, for that, let us dive into some source code.

First the easy part, `cancel(true)`:

```
public final boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
    return future.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
}
```

This cancel ends up calling the following code:

```
boolean innerCancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
    for (;;) {
        int s = getState();
        if (ranOrCancelled(s))
            return false;
        if (compareAndSetState(s, CANCELLED)) // <-----
            break;
    }
    if (mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        Thread r = runner;
        if (r != null)
            r.interrupt(); // <-----
    }
    releaseShared(0);
    done(); // <-----
    return true;
}
```

The SwingWorker state is set to `CANCELLED`, the thread is interrupted and `done()` is called, however this is not SwingWorker's done, but the `future` done(), which is specified when the variable is instantiated in the SwingWorker constructor:

```
future = new FutureTask<T>(callable) {
    @Override
    protected void done() {
        doneEDT();  // <-----
        setState(StateValue.DONE);
    }
};
```

And the `doneEDT()` code is:

```
private void doneEDT() {
    Runnable doDone =
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                done(); // <-----
            }
        };
    if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
        doDone.run(); // <-----
    } else {
        doSubmit.add(doDone);
    }
}
```

Which calls the SwingWorkers's `done()` directly if we are in the EDT which is our case. At this point the SwingWorker should stop, no more `publish()` should be called, this is easy enough to demonstrate with the following modification:

```
while(!isCancelled()) {
    textArea.append("Calling publish\n");
    publish("Writing...\n");
}
```

However we still get a "Writing..." message from process(). So let us see how is process() called. The source code for `publish(...)` is

```
protected final void publish(V... chunks) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (doProcess == null) {
            doProcess = new AccumulativeRunnable<V>() {
                @Override
                public void run(List<V> args) {
                    process(args); // <-----
                }
                @Override
                protected void submit() {
                    doSubmit.add(this); // <-----
                }
            };
        }
    }
    doProcess.add(chunks);  // <-----
}
```

We see that the `run()` of the Runnable `doProcess` is who ends up calling `process(args)`, but this code just calls `doProcess.add(chunks)` not `doProcess.run()` and there's a `doSubmit` around too. Let's see `doProcess.add(chunks)`.

```
public final synchronized void add(T... args) {
    boolean isSubmitted = true;
    if (arguments == null) {
        isSubmitted = false;
        arguments = new ArrayList<T>();
    }
    Collections.addAll(arguments, args); // <-----
    if (!isSubmitted) { //This is what will make that for multiple publishes only one process is executed
        submit(); // <-----
    }
}
```

So what `publish()` actually does is adding the chunks into some internal ArrayList `arguments` and calling `submit()`. We just saw that submit just calls `doSubmit.add(this)`, which is this very same `add` method, since both `doProcess` and `doSubmit` extend `AccumulativeRunnable<V>`, however this time around `V` is `Runnable` instead of `String` as in `doProcess`. So a chunk is the runnable that calls `process(args)`. However the `submit()` call is a completely different method defined in the class of `doSubmit`:

```
private static class DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable
     extends AccumulativeRunnable<Runnable> implements ActionListener {
    private final static int DELAY = (int) (1000 / 30);
    @Override
    protected void run(List<Runnable> args) {
        for (Runnable runnable : args) {
            runnable.run();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void submit() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, this); // <-----
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        run(); // <-----
    }
}
```

It creates a Timer that fires the `actionPerformed` code once after `DELAY` miliseconds. Once the event is fired the code will be enqueued in the EDT which will call an internal `run()` which ends up calling `run(flush())` of `doProcess` and thus executing `process(chunk)`, where chunk is the flushed data of the `arguments` ArrayList. I skipped some details, the chain of "run" calls is like this:

- doSubmit.run()
- doSubmit.run(flush()) //Actually a loop of runnables but will only have one (*)
- doProcess.run()
- doProcess.run(flush())
- process(chunk)

(*)The boolean `isSubmited` and `flush()` (which resets this boolean) make it so additional calls to publish don't add doProcess runnables to be called in  doSubmit.run(flush()) however their data is not ignored. Thus executing a single process for any amount of publishes called during the life of a Timer.

All in all, what `publish("Writing...")` does is scheduling the call to `process(chunk)` in the EDT *after* a DELAY. This explains why even after we cancelled the thread and no more publishes are done, still one process execution appears, because the moment we cancel the worker there's (with high probability) a Timer that will schedule a `process()` after `done()` is already scheduled.

Why is this Timer used instead of just scheduling process() in the EDT with an `invokeLater(doProcess)`? To implement the performance optimization explained in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish(V...)):

> Because the process method is invoked asynchronously on the Event
>   Dispatch Thread multiple invocations to the publish method might occur
>   before the process method is executed. For performance purposes all
>   these invocations are coalesced into one invocation with concatenated
>   arguments.
>       For example:
>
> ```
>  publish("1");
>  publish("2", "3");
>  publish("4", "5", "6");
>
> might result in:
>  process("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
> ```

We now know that this works because all the publishes that occur within a DELAY interval are adding their `args` into that internal variable we saw `arguments` and the `process(chunk)` will execute with all that data in one go.

**IS THIS A BUG? WORKAROUND?**

It's hard to tell If this is a bug or not, It might make sense to process the data that the background thread has published, since the work is actually done and you might be interested in getting the GUI updated with as much info as you can (if that's what `process()` is doing, for example). And then it might not make sense if `done()` requires to have all the data processed and/or a call to process() after done() creates data/GUI inconsistencies.

There's an obvious workaround if you don't want any new process() to be executed after done(), simply check if the worker is cancelled in the `process` method too!

```
@Override
protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
    if (isCancelled()) return;
    String string = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
    textArea.append(string);
}
```

It's more tricky to make done() be executed after that last process(), for example done could just use also a timer that will schedule the actual done() work after >DELAY. Although I can't think this is would be a common case since if you cancelled It shouldn't be important to miss one more process() when we know that we are in fact cancelling the execution of all the future ones.

Comment: Sorry for the big ramble :P

Comment: Wow... What a really great explanation! Couldn't expect any better! Thanks so much for taking some time unveiling SwingWorker's behind scenes :)

Comment: Brilliant explanation... thanks for not only analysing the source but taking all this time to explain it in plain English.  Strikes me that this is not a bug as such, but a somewhat unsatisfactory implementation.  Don't get me wrong, I think SwingWorker is brilliant and use it all the time, but I think there should be better visibility (a useful handle or two) to this internal mechanism, potentially enabling users to wait until all published chunks have "gone off".

Comment: I also note (this is why I ended up here) that it appears that `java.awt.Robot` does not appear to take any account of `SW.publish/process` stuff in its method `waitForIdle()`.   I have found this out during unit testing stuff, where I tend to use `Robot` a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Having read DSquare's superb answer, and concluded from it that some subclassing would be needed, I've come up with this idea for anyone who needs to make sure all published chunks have been processed in the EDT before moving on.

NB I tried to write it in Java rather than Jython (my language of choice and officially the best language in the world), but it is a bit complicated because, for example, `publish` is `final`, so you'd have to invent another method to call it, and also because you have to (yawn) parameterise everything with generics in Java.

This code should be understandable by any Java person: just to help, with `self.publication_counter.get()`, this evaluates to `False` when the result is 0.

```
# this is how you say Worker... is a subclass of SwingWorker in Python/Jython
class WorkerAbleToWaitForPublicationToFinish( javax.swing.SwingWorker ):

    # __init__ is the constructor method in Python/Jython
    def __init__( self ):

        # we just add an "attribute" (here, publication_counter) to the object being created (self) to create a field of the new object
        self.publication_counter = java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger()

    def await_processing_of_all_chunks( self ):
        while self.publication_counter.get():
            time.sleep( 0.001 )

    # fully functional override of the Java method     
    def process( self, chunks ):
        for chunk in chunks:
            pass
            # DO SOMETHING WITH EACH CHUNK

        # decrement the counter by the number of chunks received
        # NB do this AFTER dealing with the chunks 
        self.publication_counter.addAndGet( - len( chunks ) )

    # fully functional override of the Java method     
    def publish( self, *chunks ):
        # increment the counter by the number of chunks received
        # NB do this BEFORE publishing the chunks
        self.publication_counter.addAndGet( len( chunks ))
        self.super__publish( chunks )
```

So in your calling code, you put something like:

```
    engine.update_xliff_task.get()
    engine.update_xliff_task.await_processing_of_all_chunks()
```

PS the use of a `while` clause like this (i.e. a polling technique) is hardly elegant.  I looked at the available `java.util.concurrent` classes such as `CountDownLatch` and `Phaser` (both with thread-blocking methods), but I don't think either would suit for this purpose...

***later***

I was interested enough in this to tweak a proper concurrency class (written in Java, found on the Apache site) called `CounterLatch`.  Their version stops the thread at `await()` **if** a value of an `AtomicLong` counter is reached.  My version here allows to you to either to do that, or the opposite: to say "wait **until** the counter reaches a certain value before lifting the latch":

NB use of `AtomicLong` for `signal` and `AtomicBoolean` for `released`: because in the original Java they use the `volatile` keyword.  I think using the atomic classes will achieve the same purpose.

```
class CounterLatch():
    def __init__( self, initial = 0, wait_value = 0, lift_on_reached = True ):
        self.count = java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong( initial )
        self.signal = java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong( wait_value )

        class Sync( java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer ):
            def tryAcquireShared( sync_self, arg ):
                if lift_on_reached:
                    return -1 if (( not self.released.get() ) and self.count.get() != self.signal.get() ) else 1
                else:
                    return -1 if (( not self.released.get() ) and self.count.get() == self.signal.get() ) else 1
            def tryReleaseShared( self, args ):
                return True

        self.sync = Sync()
        self.released = java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean() # initialised at False

    def await( self, *args ):
        if args:
            assert len( args ) == 2
            assert type( args[ 0 ] ) is int
            timeout = args[ 0 ]
            assert type( args[ 1 ] ) is java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
            unit = args[ 1 ]
            return self.sync.tryAcquireSharedNanos(1, unit.toNanos(timeout))
        else:
            self.sync.acquireSharedInterruptibly( 1 )

    def count_relative( self, n ):
        previous = self.count.addAndGet( n )
        if previous == self.signal.get():
            self.sync.releaseShared( 0 )
        return previous
```

So my code now looks like this:

In the SwingWorker constructor:

```
self.publication_counter_latch = CounterLatch()
```

In SW.publish:

```
self.publication_counter_latch.count_relative( len( chunks ) )
self.super__publish( chunks )
```

In the thread waiting for chunk processing to stop:

```
worker.publication_counter_latch.await()
```