# cleaning up after using a SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, unit-testing, swingworker

NB This is not about terminating a worker thread.  It's about the aftermath of a normal termination.

I'm calling `execute` in the EDT, so this spawns a "worker thread".
I'm calling `worker.get()` in a `Callable` which I submit to an `ExecutorService`, specifically a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

The task ends OK (i.e. `worker.get()` returns with a result, and the `Callable` also ends OK).

I call `shutdown()` on the `Executor Service`: method terminates normally.

The puzzle comes when I examine the threads after this.  This is in the context of unit testing, and I basically want to kill off all the activity which has been started during the last test.

I'm listing all the threads, and in addition to the various ones which were present before the test started I see this:

> # thread Thread[pool-2-thread-1,5,main], state WAITING, alive
>   True, interrupted False, thread group main
>    # thread
>   Thread[SwingWorker-pool-4-thread-1,5,main], state WAITING, alive True,
>   interrupted False, thread group main

The trouble is, as the tests get run, the newly constructed "Application" object makes a new thread pool each time, and more and more `SwingWorkers` get created... and none of these threads appears to transition to the `Thread.State` "TERMINATED" (which presumably would mean they would then cease to be listed).

I then tried calling `join` on the "SwingWorker-pool-4-thread" `Thread`... but this causes my current thread to hang.

Can anyone explain what's going on here and how to transition these threads to "TERMINATED"?

***later***

Response to 2 helpful comments.  10 threads, right.  My thinking is just that a test if it fails (or an exception occurs) this can leave things in a troublesome state: suppose, in a functional test, 3 SWs are involved, and all sorts of `publish/process` stuff is going on, not to mention various `Runnable`s in the EDT.  Before moving to the next test I want everything to be shut, closed, ended, killed, returned to a pristine, virginal state!

To ensure all `Runnable`s have ended we have `Robot.waitForIdle`(). I've also thought up a strategy for ensuring the `publish/process` thing has ended: [SwingWorker, done() is executed before process() calls are finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958793/swingworker-done-is-executed-before-process-calls-are-finished/35526033#35526033)... . But in fact the latter, useful as it is, presupposes that the testing code **knows** which SWs to call the method on... I'm looking for a blunderbus, which will just kill em stone dead.

The `toString` for these Thread objects shows clearly which has been created since starting the latest test... but I don't know how to kill 'em off.  Isn't it the case that "WAITING" means that, vampire-like, they might rise up again and do all sorts of bad things?  And just leaving vast numbers of "waiting" Threads hanging around, potentially running into their hundreds, seems a bit... untidy!

***even later***

Ah yes, getting hold of the `AppContext` object is vital because you need to "reset" this in order to prevent `RejectedExecutionException`.  See my answer for how to do in Jython.

I also note that in the SW API doc it says

> Because SwingWorker implements Runnable, a SwingWorker can be
>   submitted to an Executor for execution.

This presumably means that you don't have to use SW's default executor at all.  Might be the way to go, but unless needed for another reason in the app code, it kind of violates the principle of not tailoring the app code for the convenience of the testing code...

Comment: SwingWoker has its own ExecutorService (with a fixed pool of 10 threads), which all SwingWorkers use, these are daemon threads, so they won't stop the JVM from exiting normally. Typically, you don't need to worry about them

Comment: Specifically in the context of unit testing... you have two interacting bits of code: there's the code that creates and submits the tasks to the Executor, and then there's the code that's actually *in* the task. I would design (at least) one unit test for the task itself, and another unit test for the task-submitter; in this latter unit test I would mock the ExecutorService itself. The task test will verify behaviour of the task.

Comment: Thanks to both... see additional note.

Comment: AFAIK `WAITING` means they are doing nothing. In the case of the `SwingWorker`, these threads are pooled, so, yes, the worker will try and re-use them if it can. Because in the "normal" operations, the worker needs to deal with the fact that the `doInBackground` method might explode horrible, it's already designed to deal with it (which is why `get` throws an `Exception`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm not sure I see the need to do this, but...

Having dug through the `SwingWorker` source code, the worker uses the `private` `getWorkersExecutorService` method to get the `ExecutorService` for the current JVM.

This uses the `AppContext` to store an instance of `ExecutorService`, from which all instances of `SwingWorker` (for the JVM) will draw threads from to execute their functionality.

So, if you do something like...

```
AppContext appContext = AppContext.getAppContext();
ExecutorService executorService = (ExecutorService) appContext.get(SwingWorker.class);
System.out.println(executorService);
```

will print out something like...

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4554617c[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

(this assumes you've previously started a `SwingWorker` otherwise it will return `null`)

But, what does this mean?  Well, we can now gain direct access the `ExecutorService` for all the `SwingWorker`s (the apocalypse may now start)

This means you can shutdown the service and even remove it from the `AppContext`, for example...

```
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Ending");
        return null;
    }
};
worker.execute();
synchronized (SwingWorker.class) {
    AppContext appContext = AppContext.getAppContext();
    ExecutorService executorService = (ExecutorService) appContext.get(SwingWorker.class);
    System.out.println(executorService);
    System.out.println("Shutting down");
    executorService.shutdownNow();
    try {
        System.out.println("Waiting");
        executorService.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    appContext.remove(SwingWorker.class);
}
```

In my testing, it outputs...

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4554617c[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
Shutting down
Waiting
Starting
Done
```

So the worker doesn't even get a chance to start.  If I place a delay in (after calling `execute`), `shutdownNow` basically hammers it and won't wait for the worker to finish, but if I use `shutdown` it does, so, there you have it.

I should add, AFAIK `WAITING` means they are doing nothing. In the case of the `SwingWorker`, these threads are pooled, so, yes, the worker will try and re-use them if it can, BUT because in the "normal" operations of the `SwingWorker`, the worker needs to deal with the fact that the `doInBackground` method might explode horrible, it's already designed to deal with it (which is why `get` throws an `Exception`), so unless you have a particular use case, I'm not really sure you need to go to this much trouble, just saying

Comment: Thanks very much.  Could you possibly explain where AppContext comes from?  It doesn't seem to be found in my API documentation (Java 7)...

Comment: `AppContext` is an internal (sun) API, I only know that `SwingWorker` makes use of it

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to MadProgrammer's answer, for which I thank him/her.

Jython users can access and use private methods.  Below, to get all threads, and also to get the SW's `ExecutorService`.

Running the code below shows, indeed, that the "SwingWorker..." thread disappears from the listing of threads at the end due to the `shutdownNow`.  This doesn't stop 3 new threads persisting at the end, "TimerQueue", "AWT-Windows" and "Java2D Disposer"... but these are all in the "system" `ThreadGroup`, and the only "main" group thread remaining is the current thread, so I'd say problem (if there is one) solved!

```
def get_all_threads():
    private_static_method = java.lang.Thread.getDeclaredMethod( 'getThreads' )
    private_static_method.accessible = True
    # invoking a static method: one param, None
    return private_static_method.invoke( None )

def show_all_threads():
    for thread in get_all_threads():
        print( '  # ID %d: thread %s, state %s, alive %s, interrupted %s, thread group %s' % ( 
            thread.id, thread, thread.state, thread.alive, thread.isInterrupted(), thread.threadGroup.name,) )
        if thread is java.lang.Thread.currentThread():
            print( '  # --> current thread' )

class Worker( javax.swing.SwingWorker ):
    def doInBackground( self ):
        print( 'Starting' )
        time.sleep( 3 )
        print( 'Ending' )

Worker().execute()

private_static_method = javax.swing.SwingWorker.getDeclaredMethod( 'getWorkersExecutorService' )
private_static_method.accessible = True
exec_serv = private_static_method.invoke( None )

show_all_threads()
exec_serv.shutdownNow()
print( '# shutDownNow ordered...' )
exec_serv.awaitTermination( java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.DAYS )
print( '# ...terminated' )
show_all_threads()

# now "reset" the AppContext object so future executes won't raise a RejectedExecutionException
app_context = sun.awt.AppContext.getAppContext()
app_context.remove( javax.swing.SwingWorker )
```